# xampp apache couldn't be stopped

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am working in windows 8 OS. And I have edited something in my php.ini.. In order to save changes or see the changes I have to stop my apache server. But it can't be stopped. The xampp control panel stop working when I stop the apache How can I fix this? Please, I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install Apache as service when installing XAMPP?

Comment: @ApulGupta, yes.. I have installed it together with mysql..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start
Run
Type "Services.msc"
Find the "Apache" service
Right click and stop

Comment: This will only work if user has Admin right & apache is installed as service.

Comment: Thanks.. It works. I actually used the task manager to restart. :)